# How to make full backup of Sharepoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, backup

Is there any way to make a **full backup** of Sharepoint Online web site based on Office 365 without third-party tools? Tried to google it, but found only ways to manually backup list or libraries. I'm need to save user properties, permissions, webparts, etc. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

No. You need third-party tools in order to do that.
One "Workaround" (that does not give you all you want, and that is not supported) is that You save the Site as a Template and select "Include Content".

[image: Link that shows how to save site as template]

[image: Choose to Include Content]

You can then later download your wsp-file from the Solution Gallery and save it on disk.

Comment: This will not work for publishing sites

Comment: Will not work or is not supported? @robertLindgren . Ilya, are you using Publishing Sites?

Comment: Both, is not supported and most of the time fails.